# How to remove special characters from tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using the tinymce editor in my web page. When I try to post some comment, it posts in the following format:

```
<p>&lt;p&gt;Hi&lt;/p&gt;<br />&lt;p&gt;Lauren how are you?&lt;/p&gt;</p>
```

instead of:

```
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Lauren how are you?</p>
```

I have tried to sort this out but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh it was so easy, ok i got it,

here we go [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

anyways thanks so much SO :)

Comment: You Should've mentioned `PHP` tag too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `html_entity_decode()` also.

```
echo  html_entity_decode('&lt;p&gt;Hi&lt;/p&gt;<br />&lt;p&gt;Lauren how are you?&lt;/p&gt;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) Method.

```
str = "<p>&lt;p&gt;Hi&lt;/p&gt;<br />&lt;p&gt;Lauren how are you?&lt;/p&gt;</p>";

document.write(decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
```